# What is the difference between base shear and pseudo lateral load in seismic analysis of buildings?

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis

What is the difference between base shear and pseudo lateral load in seismic analysis of buildings or are they the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base shear is the **result** of any type of analysis, including pseudo lateral load and seismic analysis.